# Is a quadratic map with limited domain a linear growth function?

Tags: calculus

The definition of a linear growth map being,
$\forall x \in Dom(f), |f(x)| \leq c(|x| + 1)$

If I have the function $f(x) = x^2$ and $x\in[0,a], a < \infty$. Is it considered a linear growth function, despite being an obvious non-linear function?

Makes sense to me because, $\frac{x^2}{|x| + 1} \leq c$ is respected since for any value of the domain of $f$, I can always get a constant $c$ that satisfies it.

Comment: That's correct. Actually, all continuous functions are "of linear growth" (as you say) on compact sets. The notion is relevant only on unbounded domains.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense, worth taking a note on it.